# What is customer/service_head.tpl file in Xcart?

Tags: x-cart

Am newbie in X cart.
How load customer/service_head.tpl in Xcart and not included,I can't saw that file in skin/customer folder.Is there any process to run that file display in x cart?Am So confused don't know what's wrong.

Please Give me Solution.

Answer (score 0):

The file is located here
./skin/common_files/customer/service_head.tpl

The file is loaded from the file like 
skin/**your_skin_name**/customer/home.tpl:  {include file="customer/service_head.tpl"}

or from 
skin/**common_files**/customer/home.tpl by default

Try our 'Webmaster mode' feature
 
https://demo.x-cart.com/demo_goldplus/admin/editor_mode.php
https://help.x-cart.com/index.php?title=X-Cart:Using_Webmaster_mode

[image]